# how to kick someone from videocall agora with flutter

Tags: flutter, agora.io

I'm creating an app for video or voice call with flutter for Android / iOS. And I want to enable someone to kick another from a call. Is there anyone who knows how? any idea?

There are lots of functions in RtcEngine() and I don't know which one would remove another users.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways that I can think of to do this:

### RTM (new name: Signalling)

Using RTM, you could send a message to the user you want to kick, which reacts to logic on the device that then restricts it from rejoining the room. For example, send a plain text message such as `"kicked_from:channel-id-here"`, or a json string if you want to add more complex messages that are decoded by your application:

```
"{\"action\":\"kick\",\"channel-id\",\"reason\":\"abuse\"}"
```

This is then saved into a map for example, which then is checked whenever they try to rejoin a channel.
RTM can be found [here](https://pub.dev/packages/agora_rtm).

### Via Token Server

When kicking someone from your room, you could send a message to your token server with a specific user's ID.
The token server could then revoke that token from joining the channel, resulting in them then leaving the channel. You'd have to then add some logic to either the token server or the client to prevent that user to request a new token and rejoining.

Comment: Are you sure there is not a function in RtcEngine() without api_call and backend works?

Comment: RTM would be a pretty easy solution without needing a backend call. Otherwise you could checkout stream messages, but they're not so reliable.